# importing wxpython module into python

Tags: python, wxpython

I just installed wxPython 2.8 with the following:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Everything was installed but when I do:

```
import wx
```

in python, I get

```
ImportError: No module named wx
```

I do realize that wx is not on python's path. How can I get it on python's path? I've tried sys.path.append, but for some reason that doesn't work and it only adds it to the path temporarily.

I'm running python 2.7.2 (I don't know if that matters)

Comment: What OS? Is there a reason you built from source rather than use the binary installers?

Comment: Why not install `pythoncard` from your package manager? Do you really need to compile wxPython manually?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Linux Mint, you can run the command `sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8 python-wxtools wx2.8-i18n`, and that *should* get you going.

Comment: Doing that still gives me the same error. That's why I tried to build it from source. If I could just figure out how to get python to find the wx module, I think it'll work...hopefully

Comment: Did you install python manually or are you using the version from your package manager?

Comment: i installed python from source too. How do I install python from package manager? Because I didn't find any packages available

Comment: `apt-get` is a command-line package manager (for Debian systems, at least).  Did you run the command through a Terminal?

Comment: I do know about apt-get. I meant that I don't know the name of the package that I'm supposed to supply to apt-get install

Comment: It was, as provided:  `python-wxgtk2.8`,  `python-wxtools`, and  `wx2.8-i18n`.  All three of these can be installed in the same go using apt-get, which is what was given in my original answer.